# The disabled attr doesn't work in Huawei Browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, huawei-developers

The disabled attr seems not work in Huawei Browser,the saab option can be select.But it works in other Browers. I have tried the prop,it doesn't work as well.

```
<select id="cartype">
  <option value ="volvo"  >Volvo</option>
  <option value ="saab" disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

document.getElementById("cartype").options[1].disabled="true";
$("#cartype option[value=saab]").prop("disabled",true);
```